# I want to programatically take screen shot of my android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to programmatically take screen shot of my android application which is a `video calling` application by using openSIPS protocol. While on the video call, I need to take the screen shots. I have already tried something but it gives the screenshot except the videocall fragment.

Here is my try:

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = mVideoView.getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        //rootView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                //MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        // rootView.layout(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        rootView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        // rootView.destroyDrawingCache();
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

The videoView extends an SurfaceView, which has its content not go through the drawing cache, thus getting it will only returnes a black screen instead of a capture of the video layout. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the following URL


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276346/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-and-save-it-on-gallery

Comment: But its not work, because here I need to try with a videoview

Comment: there are lots of option available:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582603/programmatic-screencapture-on-mobile-device

Comment: `SurfaceView` is a quite diffrent from normal `View`. and this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289544/taking-screenshot-programmatically-doesnt-capture-the-contents-of-surfaceview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok now, I got the perfect answer for me.
Here it is.

```
if (InCallActivity.capture) {
            int widthx = width;
            int heightx = height;
            int screenshotSize = widthx * heightx;
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, widthx, heightx, GL10.GL_RGBA,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
            int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];
            bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
            bb = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthx, heightx,
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize - widthx,
                    -widthx, 0, 0, widthx, heightx);
            pixelsBuffer = null;

            short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
            ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);

            // Making created bitmap (from OpenGL points) compatible with
            // Android bitmap
            for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {
                short v = sBuffer[i];
                sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v & 0x1f) << 11) | (v & 0x7e0) | ((v & 0xf800) >> 11));
            }
            sb.rewind();
            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);
            InCallActivity.captureBmp = bitmap.copy(
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
            InCallActivity.capture = false;
        }
```

I put this code inside `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` method of my `class Renderer` , and it seems working. Here `InCallActivity` is the class where I using the GlSurfaceView.
I got this answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554553/cocos2dhow-to-create-bitmap-from-glsurfaceview). Thanks for supports. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that

```
Bitmap bitmap;
  View v1 = findViewById(R.id.rlid);// get ur root view id
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and then for saving

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
  File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "test.jpg")
  f.createNewFile();
  FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
  fo.close();
```

Source: [how to take screenshot programmatically and save it on gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276346/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-and-save-it-on-gallery)

or you can also check this link [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Comment: check the second link i posted, it has the best answer

Comment: All are pointing same solution, but its not helping me coz surfaceview is quite different.